# Javascript: Why is a ternary expression result returned when placed after a logical OR?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, ternary-operator

I can't find an answer to this, after a little research.

Given this:

`'Hello' || true ? true : false`

The result is `true`, which to me, doesn't make sense. Because the first value was truthy, I would expect the result of this to be `'Hello'`, and skip the ternary. However, what it instead does is use the result of the ternary.

Why is that?

Comment: Is the same as `if('Hello' || true) echo true;`

the condition is `true`, so the output is "true"

Comment: `"I would expect the result of this to be 'Hello'"` Why?

Comment: Operator precedence here... http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/ys7zbn3x/ You probably are expecting the ternary operator to take precedence over the `||`, but it just doesn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: `'Hello' || (true ? true : false)` would satisfy your expectations. Or shorter: `'Hello' || true`. Or even shorter: `'Hello'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's because of the operators precedence in JavaScript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

`||` is interpretet before `?`, hence it is an equivalent to:

```
('Hello' || true) ? true : false
```

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to the priority of operations.

The `||` operator has a higher priority than `?:`. This means that it's the same as this:

`('Hello' || true) ? true : false`

`('Hello' || true)` is truthy, so `truthy ? true : false` will return `true`